# Find out windows shortcut path

Tags: python, shortcut

In windows, I can make a number of shortcuts. I want to know whether the program is opened as shortcut, or itself. And finally I hope to know where the shortcuts path location is in my program. Unfortunately, I use **python** so I hope a solution in python.

Answer (score 1):

`__file__` will get you the name of the invoked script. If it is a link, it should change accordingly.

You can check if the file is a link via the following:

```
import os       
islink = os.path.islink(__file__)
```

`islink` will contain a `boolean` value with the answer.

I tested this out on Ubuntu, but this should in theory work on Windows, also, via POSIX.

More info:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this question:

> And finally I hope to know where the shortcuts path location is in my
>   program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run a my .py with shortcut, *__file__* represent just a .py path, so I can't determine with *__file__* sorry. And what I want to do is finding out a shortcut file's path(.lnk) not a .py path.

Comment: Hmm...that sounds like it might be an unexpected platform difference. On Ubuntu, if I invoke the script with a symlink, `__file__` is a symlink, and `os.path.islink` returns true. Perhaps on Windows symlinks aren't supported by the Python runtime, and so `islink` always returns false...

Comment: @KenHampson Let me first try to make Question clear-
A program is already running in your Windows box and you want to find out if its opened by a symbolic link (.lnk file) or not. If its opened by a sym link, you want to identify the file and get path to parent file.

if I am wrong please make your Question clear.

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan Right, I want it! I want to know the path of sym link file in python env.

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim When you open a symbolic link. The parent file is opened. So after its opened you cant identify whether it was opened by a shortcut file or directly on the parent file.

So According to my knowledge your desired task can not be performed. I am looking forward to see if anyone has work around to solve his problem.